# Streaming Audio MMS:// to the iPhone

Tags: iphone, streaming, mms

I'd like to stream a `mms:// url` to my iPhone app, but so far information on the topic is hard to come by.  I know there are a couple apps out there that can do it already (FStream, WunderRadio, Tuner), and I've read a few notes about them possibly using libmms and ffmpeg to accomplish this task.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?  Is there a library out there that I'm missing, or some example to do this already?  I was hoping this was going to be as easy as a simple

`[someLibrary streamMMSUrl:@"mms://mymmsurlhere.com"]`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i want to do the same, but seems, no solution yet.

Comment: I've given up, moved onto the next app idea :)

Comment: Is there no solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the libmms library to read MMS or MMS over HTTP streams. This is not straightforward but some existing apps (and FStream probably) use this approach. To get libmms working on the iPhone, you can find some informations on the WunderRadio site : http://www.wunderradio.com/code.html.

Comment: Yes, a few published apps use it, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How to import this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to play mms:// streams directly with the iOS SDK. You'll have to use a third-party library like libmms or FFmpeg.

If you don't want to deal with all this stuff you can use the [RadioTunes SDK for iOS](http://www.binpress.com/app/radiotunes-sdk-for-ios/596?ad=5107) framework I built which supports the http and mms protocols and can play mp3, aac, aac+ and wma audio streams.

You can start streaming mms audio streams with the RadioTunes SDK with just 2 lines of code:

```
MMSRadio *mmsRadio = [[MMSRadio alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mms://mmsurlhere.com"]];
[mmsRadio play];
```

Comment: In the future, please flag duplicate questions as duplicate instead of posting the same answer verbatim on them. I'm leaving this answer, because it is helpful and you've made the needed disclosure. However, if those duplicates get merged into _this_ question, you'd have answered it five times.

Comment: Ok Tim, I'll do that the next time I see a duplicate question. Still learning the Stackoverflow ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the kxmovie (https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) as example

I searched in many examples but only this code worked.

In the url I replace mms:// to mmsh:// - MMS (Microsoft Media Server) protocol over HTTP.

Look ffmpeg documentation (http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#mmst)