# How to stream MMS:// link on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Streaming Audio MMS:// to the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256720/streaming-audio-mms-to-the-iphone)

I have been trying to find the solution for this but I haven't found out anything yet. Please help me with this if you have any idea about this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMS is Microsoft's (now deprecated) data transfer protocol, intended for Windows Media Video (WMV) and Windows Media Audio (WMA) streams. Those do not play on iPhone's - so unfortunately the simple answer to your question is - "you can't".

If you do want to play video or audio on the iPhone - I suggest going with a streaming service provider. You can read about the technical requirements of: [iPhone streaming](http://www.netromedia.com/stream-to-iphone-ipad-and-ipod/) <-- (same as iPad actually)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a library that supports the mms protocol. Basically you have two choices: libmms or FFmpeg. Since you'll also need to decode the wma audio streams I suggest you use FFmpeg for both the mms protocol and wma decoding functionalities.

Please have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445918/is-it-possible-to-decode-an-mmswma2-stream-using-audio-units-on-the-iphone/8136244#8136244) to see which FFmpeg functions you should use to play mms streams.